# How to construct a unordered binary tree from text file

Tags: java

Dear Friends I am an intermediate java user. I am stuck in a following problem. I want to construct a unordered binary tree [or general tree having at most two nodes] from a multi line (let say 40 lines) text file. The text file is then divided into two halfs; let say 20:20 lines. Then for each half a specific (let say hash) value is calculated and stored in the root node. So each node contains four elements. Two pointers to the two children (left and right) and two hashes of the two halfs of the original file. Next for each half (20 lines) the process is repeated until at each leaf we have a single line of text. Let the node have

```
public class BinaryTree {

    private BinaryTreeNode leftNode, rightNode;

    private String leftHash,rightHash;

}
```

I need help for writing the tree construction and searching functions. Well searching is performed by entering a line. Then hash code is created for this query line and compared against the two hashes saved at each node. If the hash of query line is close to leftHas then leftNode is accessed and if the hash of query line is close to rightHash then rightNode is accessed. The process continues until an exact hash is found. 
I just need the tree construction and search teachnique. The hash comparison etc are not a problem

Comment: Well... Start with reading up on how to read files with java.

Comment: That is not a problem... Actually the problem is a small part of a big project so I just used this technique to get answer. I can then use it in my problem

Comment: What are you exactly trying to accomplish? Are you trying to accomplish that we make your code for you? I do not quite understand.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to start by reading the file into a string.

The first character in the string could be used as the root.  Root + 1 would be the left, root + 2 would be the right

Consider left node of the root (Root + 1), you could also consider this as Root + N.  Meaning that the right node would be Root + N + 1.

You can now recursively solve this problem by establishing which Node you are currently on, and setting the left and right now respectively.

So lets think about it,

You have the root node, left node, and right node established.  At this point you have used 3 letters/numbers (it really doesnt matter if it is unordered).  The next step would be to move down one level and start filling the left, you have the root, you need left and right nodes.  Then move to the right node, do the left and right node of this and so on and so forth.

Think about that for a little bit and see where you get.

Cheers,

Mike

EDIT:

To search,

Searching a binary tree is also a recursive theme. (I thought you previously said the tree was unordered, which may change how the tree is laid out if it is suppose to be order).

If it is unordered, you can simply recurse the tree in a manner such that

A.) Check root node
B.) Check left node
C.) Continue checking left nodes until either there is a match, or no more left nodes to check
D.) Recurse back 1, check right node
E.) Check left nodes,
F.) Recuse back, check right node

This theme will continue until eventually you have checked ALL left nodes first, and then the right nodes.  The KEY to this, is at any point you have a root node, go left first, then right.  (I forget what traversal type this is, but there are others if you wish to implement them over this, i personally think this is the easiest to remember).

You will then repeat for right child of Root node.

If at any time you get a match, exit.

Remember this is recursive, so make sure you think your way through this step by step.  It is recursive by definition, in that you will always do steps x,y,z for each part of the tree.

To beat a dead horse, lets look at just 3 nodes to start.
(simplified)

First the root,

```
if(root == (what your looking for))
{ 
   return root
}
else if(root.leftNode == (what your looking for))
{
   return root.leftNode
}
else if(root.rightNode == (what your looking for))
{
   return root.rightNode
}
else
{
   System.out.println("Value not found")
}
```

If you have 5 nodes, that would be root would have a left and right, and the root.leftNode would have a left and right... You would repeat the steps above on root.leftNode also, then search root.rightNode

If you have 7 nodes, you would search ALL of root.leftNode and then recurse back to search root.leftNode.

I hope this helps,

pictures work much better in my opinion when talking about traversing trees.

Perhaps look here for a better visual 
     http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/03/binary-tree-in-java/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try it but how about search since at each node I have to decide go to left child or right child. So I am a bit confused one how to write root.leftChild.LeftChild... and so on. I mean I have to search only a single path to leaf not the entire tree. The path is guided by the info stored at each node